# No se asignan los valores de la variable al vector/array

Tags: array, c, variables, vectores

Tengo que Ingresar diez números enteros y cargar
un vector con aquellos números positivos. Pense en usar un ciclo for para hacer las 10 vueltas y anidarle jn do-while que controle que el numero ingresado sea mayor a 0 y entonces recien ahí agregarlo al vector. Lo intente de dos formas, la primera me manera toma los valores
ingresados y cuando es menor a 0 mantiene el ultimo numero en su posicion, pero
suma otra vuelta al restar i.
Código:

```
void cargar(int[]); 

int main(){
    int vec[10];
    cargar(vec);
    return 0;
} 
void cargar(int vec[]){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){      
        int num;        
        printf("\nIngrese un numero: ");
        scanf("%d",&num);   
        if(num>0){                        
            printf("\nnumero: %d", num);
            vec[i]=num;
            i++;
        }else{
            i--;
        }    
        printf("\nEl %d valor: %d ",i,vec[i]);   
    }    
}
```

En el segundo intento pense darle como valor al for una j y al vector el valor de i (como si fuera un contador). Desde el primer numero ingresado, cuando imprime el valor en cada posición del vector, muestra un numero cualquiera (48,127,etc) y no suma la variable de la posicion.
Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void cargar(int[]);
int main(){
    int vec[10];
    cargar(vec);
    return 0;
}

void cargar(int vec[]){
    int j=0;
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){      
        int num; 
        printf("\nVuelta: %d",j);    
        printf("\nIngrese un numero: ");
        scanf("%d",&num); 
        int i=0;  
        if(num>0){                        
            printf("\nnumero: %d", num);
            vec[i]=num;
            i++;
        }else{
            i=i-1;
        }
        printf("\nEl %d valor: %d ",i,vec[i]);           
    }
}
```

Desde ya, agradezco cualquier aporte.
Saludos.

Comment: Y ¿qué error te sale?

Comment: Cuando pide ingresar un numero ingreso (por ejemplo) 7 y cuando lo imprime sale que a la posicion 0 se le asigno el valor 127, y si despues ingreso 2 se le asigna un 48 por ejemplo. No es el valor ingresado, sino cualquier otro aleatorio.

Comment: 1-¿Quieres qué los resultados sean aleatorios?. 2-Si "i" Es un indice: Con cada siclo se reinicia la variable "i". Te recomiendo eliminar "i" y en su lugar usar "j". En el segundo código claro. 3-Te recomiendo qué dentro del bucle for nó inicialises la variable "num".

Comment: 1. Los valores que se asignan a cada posición deberian ser los de la variable num(siempre que sean mayores a 0). 2. Queria que la variable que define la posicion fuera distinta del bucle for, porque for si o si tiene que llegar a 10, en cambio el vector puede tener 10 posiciones u 8 o 6 o ninguno. 3. Cuando ni inicializaba la variable num dentro del for en la primer entrada asignaba bien el valor, y desde la segunda entrada asignaba cualquier valor.

Comment: 2- ...Tu decidiste la condición del bucle for. for (i=0;i<10/*Aqui decisdes la condicion. por lo tanto siemple se ejecutará 10 veces*/;i++) //Continuemos en:https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119864/sala-1-2-0

Comment: Aquí recomienda qué cuando se necesita muchos comentarios para constestar la pregunta: Qué sigamos en una sala de Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

> ... la primera me manera toma los valores ingresados y cuando es menor a 0 mantiene el ultimo numero en su posicion, pero suma otra vuelta al restar i ...

- El `for( )` ya realiza el incremento, no es necesario que incrementes tú a mano.
- El `printf( )` está mal colocado.

  ```
  void cargar(int vec[]){
    int i=0;
      for(i=0;i<10;i++){      
          int num;        
          printf("\nIngrese un numero: ");
          scanf("%d",&num);   
          if(num>0){                        
              printf("\nnumero: %d", num);
              vec[i]=num;
              printf("\nEl %d valor: %d ",i,vec[i]);   
              i++;
          }else{
              i--;
          }    
      }    
  }
  ```

Tu segundo intento es claramente incorrecto; `i` se vuelve a establecer a `0` en cada cicle, *ergo* siempre intentarás acceder a `vec[0]`. Podrías intentarlo sumando `j + i` (el índice del bucle mas tu variable), pero ese caso es equivalente a usar solamente `j`. En resumen, el segundo intento es equivalente al primero, pero mas *ofuscado* :-)